# 301 редирект с "?" в ссылке - joomla 3.7

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

Перехожу с Wordpress на Joomla, перенёс материалы, на наиболее популярные создал редирект в `.htaccess`

```
Redirect 301 /?p=858 /articles/1-proverka-pozitsij-sajta-svoimi-rukami-skript-yandex-xml
```

Но, он не работает... 
Проблема в вопросительном знаке, без него всё хорошо.
`.htaccess` стандартный, без изменений.

Answer (score 1):

Вопросительный знак в `.htaccess` по умолчанию распознаётся как модификатор регулярного выражения.

Как вариант, попробуйте экранировать этот символ.